# What is the most convenient device for Android development?

Tags: android, mobile

I'm currently developing apps for iOS, but I also want to start developing for android. The device to use for iOS development is not too hard of a choice, because, well, you don't really have much of a choice, either an iPhone, an iPad or an iPod Touch, end of story. But for Android, you have a much wider spectrum, there are many different models and many different brands. So, what would you recomend for Android development. I don't want to spend that much money, but also I want a device that won't get obsolete too soon. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Nexus series](http://www.google.com/nexus/) of dev phones should be an obvious choice since they are the first ones to be updated with new releases.

Also, as rony l pointed out, they are installed with vanilla Android and are not contaminated with 3rd party software.

Comment: And also because they come with the plain vanilla android version without any weird OEM firmware modifications (a la htc sense UI)

Answer (score 1):

I would choose the latest Nexus Series phone since it is the most '**Google Android**' phone out there. They seem to be the first ones to be updated when new releases of android comes out too! The Nexus S is a good shout since it's the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

Nexus S is a good choice.It's new android phone from Google and is quite well for development. You can read more here: http://www.google.com/nexus/#/tech-specs . But of course it's better to have some devices for testing.

Answer (score 0):

You are best to use a Google branded phone since it has no extra "skins" on top of the OS like most other brands do. The Google Nexus series is discontinued now, so get a Pixel phone instead.